# std::unordered_map iterator deference problem

Tags: c++

I have a code as below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string> 

void foo(const std::unordered_map<char, std::string>& uom){

    auto it2=uom.find('S');

    if(it2!=uom.end())  //NEVER FORGET THIS
        std::cout<< *it2 <<std::endl;
}
```

In this function I get error for *it2. The error is "invalid operands to binary expression." I couldn't find to solve this error. Can anyone help me?
Thank you.

Comment: Check the documentation for the return type of `std::unordered_map<>::find()`. Specifically the iterator type. It's not what you think it is.

Answer (score 2):

The iterator returned by `find` is an iterator over keys *and* values, in the form of a `std::pair<KeyT, ValT>` (in your case `std::pair<char, std::string>`). So in order to access the value associated with the key you've looked up, you need to use `it2->second` (i.e. the second item in the pair). See the example code in [the docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/find).